# MessagePack C++ - How to iterate through an unknown data structure?

Tags: c++, msgpack

I want to share structured data between C++ and Python languages using MessagePack like this one:

```
{
  "t" : [ [t00,...,t0N], ... , [tM0,...,tMN] ],
  "x" : [ x0,..,xN],
  "P" : [ [P00, ..., P0N], ..., [PM0,...,PMN] ]
}
```

The number of variables is optional so in some cases I will have for example only:

```
{
 "t" : [ [t00,...,t0N], ... , [tM0,...,tMN] ]
}
```

Decoding this in Python is pretty simple, my problem is to figure out
how to decode this in C++ if I don't know in advance the structure of
the data ? or the exact number of variables that I would have; is it
possible to iterate the structure in these cases?

I managed to handle a "fixed" data structure ( always with the same
number of variables ) defining a struct for example:

```
struct variables
{
   std::vector< std::vector<double> > t;
   std::vector< double > x;
   std::vector< std::vector<double> > P;
   MSPACK_DEFINE_MAP( t, x, P );
};

std::stringstream inBuffer;

.... (read data )

std::string str( inBuffer.str() );
msgpack::object_handle oh = msgpack::unpack( str.data(), str.size() );
msgpack::object deserialized = oh.get();

variables var;
deserialized.convert( var );
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this ?, how could manage optional
variables that could not appear in the structure ?; I repeat the
previous question: could I iterate an unknown data structure in C++?,
how ?

Thanks in advance!

Regards, Ernesto

Comment: I haven't used message pack, but you'll need to actually iterate through the data at each level and either know, or be able to query, what type of data is expected/present at each level.

Comment: Hi xaxxon, thanks for your reply but I exactly don't know if is it possible to iterate or "navigate" the data in message pack, maybe I have to edit my question.

Comment: which C++ msgpack implementation are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c

Comment: It looks like you get your top-level msgpack::object by calling unpack, then you can use the ::as<T>() operator to try to convert it to a specific type, such as a map.  Then from there, you can look at the key/value pairs of the map and retrieve the msgpack::object associated with each key -- and you can call as<T>() on those objects, etc.  The different types you can try to convert to are here: http://c.msgpack.org/cpp/annotated.html  things like object_map, object_array, etc.  I've never done this, but looking at the API and having used similar APIs, that seems likely to be correct.

Comment: Thanks!, I'm going to try your suggestion and see if it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to treat unknown data structure.

The first way is using parse/visitor mechanism.
Here is an example:

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// This is a simple print example visitor.
// You can do any processing in your visitor.
struct my_visitor : msgpack::null_visitor {
    bool start_map_key() {
        processing_map_key = true;
        return true;
    }
    bool end_map_key() {
        processing_map_key = false;
        return true;
    }
    bool start_array(uint32_t size) {
        std::cout << "array (size:" << size << ")[" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    bool end_array() {
        std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool visit_str(const char* v, uint32_t size) {
        if (processing_map_key) {
            std::cout << "map key:" << std::string(v, size) << std::endl;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool visit_positive_integer(uint64_t v) {
        std::cout << "found value:" << v << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool processing_map_key = false;
    std::string indent;
};


int main() {
    // create test data
    std::stringstream ss;
    msgpack::packer<std::stringstream> pk(ss);
    pk.pack_map(1);
    pk.pack("t");
    pk.pack_array(2);
    pk.pack_array(3);
    pk.pack(1);
    pk.pack(2);
    pk.pack(3);
    pk.pack_array(3);
    pk.pack(4);
    pk.pack(5);
    pk.pack(6);

    // print data (for debug)
    {
        auto oh = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size());
        std::cout << oh.get() << std::endl;
    }

    // apply visitor
    {
        my_visitor mv;
        msgpack::parse(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size(), mv);
    }
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3NrR4IMDIuLTk9e9

See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_visitor.

The other way is using `msgpack::type::variant` or `msgpack::type::variant_ref.
The former copies data, you can update it. The latter doesn't copy data. You cannot update it.
This approach requires boost. So you need to define MSGPACK_USE_BOOST. I recommend defining as a compiler option.

```
// Boost is required
#define MSGPACK_USE_BOOST

#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct my_visitor:boost::static_visitor<void> {
    void operator()(uint64_t v) const {
        std::cout << "positive insteger:" << v << std::endl;
    }
    // const is required for map key because std::multimap's key (first) is const.
    void operator()(std::string const& v) const {
        std::cout << "string:" << v << std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(std::vector<msgpack::type::variant>& v) const {
        std::cout << "array found" << std::endl;
        for (auto& e : v) {
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, e);
        }
    }
    void operator()(std::multimap<msgpack::type::variant, msgpack::type::variant>& v) const {
        std::cout << "map found" << std::endl;
        for (auto& e : v) {
            std::cout << "key:" << std::endl;
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, e.first);
            std::cout << "value:" << std::endl;
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, e.second);
        }
    }
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T const&) const {
        std::cout << "  match others" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    // create test data
    std::stringstream ss;
    msgpack::packer<std::stringstream> pk(ss);
    pk.pack_map(1);
    pk.pack("t");
    pk.pack_array(2);
    pk.pack_array(3);
    pk.pack(1);
    pk.pack(2);
    pk.pack(3);
    pk.pack_array(3);
    pk.pack(4);
    pk.pack(5);
    pk.pack(6);

    auto oh = msgpack::unpack(ss.str().data(), ss.str().size());
    std::cout << oh.get() << std::endl;

    msgpack::type::variant v = oh.get().as<msgpack::type::variant>();
    boost::apply_visitor(my_visitor(), v);
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HQwJjfwW8rLEMi0d

See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_variant

Here are exampless:
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/example/boost/msgpack_variant_capitalize.cpp
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/example/boost/msgpack_variant_mapbased.cpp

Both ways can treat unpredictable data structure. You need to do some visitor processing. If the data structure is predictable some extent, your original approach is also good way.

Comment: Hi Takatoshi Kondo, thank you very much for your answer!. I solved the problem before looking your post using the tips given by xaxxon:  I iterated over the msgpack::object using the public attributes "type" ( object_type ) and "via" ( union_type ) so accessing the different  types accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a simpler way, if you are dealing with maps (like stated in the question), not arrays.

```
msgpack::object_handle oh = msgpack::unpack(/* some data */);
std::map<std::string,msgpack::type::variant> map = obj.convert();
```

This way you will get a `map` with all the data, no need for a visitor or boost.