# How to extract value from msgpack::map using msgpack-c C++ interface

Tags: c++, msgpack

I'm *super* confused about how to extract values from a map object unpacked using msgpack-c's C++ interface. I naively assumed I could do something like this:

```cpp
msgpack::object_handle oh = msgpack::unpack(rbb_buf, bytes_recvd);
msgpack::object obj = oh.get();

if (oh.get().type == msgpack::type::MAP) {
  auto map = *obj.via.map.ptr;
  auto cps = map["status"];  // <-- This line does not compile
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
/home/evadeflow/projects/prm/csr_bridge/src/csr_bridge.cpp:97:25: error: no match for ‘operator[]’
```

I just need to get one integer value under the key `"status"` from the map. Can anybody explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been over three weeks so I finally had to get this sorted yesterday. I must have used different search terms this time around because I found another [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754902/99127) that unraveled the mystery for me.

Long-story short, I was able to use `msgpack::object::convert()` to copy the MesagePack object into a `std::map<std::string, msgpack::type::variant>` that I could then manipulate:

```cpp
msgpack::object obj = oh.get();

if (obj.type == msgpack::type::MAP) {
    std::map<std::string, msgpack::type::variant> data = obj.convert();
   ...
}
```

The `msgpack::type::variant` class has a bunch of member functions (`is_bool()`, `is_string()`, etc) for [sussing out the underlying type](http://c.msgpack.org/cpp/structmsgpack_1_1type_1_1basic__variant.html), so it was easy to index into the keys of this map and pull out the data I needed. (Fortunately, the data structure I was parsing was only one-level deep, so I didn't need to resort to the more complicated approaches discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44733325/99127).)